# How to find all the variants of the image in Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I'm using  Active Storage and I'd like to give user opportunity to rotate saved images. The problem is that variants which are already created are not replaced.

I've found outthat I can just delete variant with:

```
image.attachment.service.delete(variant.key)
```

But it's not clear if all the planned variants were created, so it would be just awesome if I could retrieve all the variants made.

I just can't figure out how to find variants linked with the image.

Comment: This should be far easier to do than it actually is... there doesn't seem to be a method I can find that does what you need...

Answer (score 0):

From https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2018/10/03/some-notes-on-whats-going-on-in-activestorage/

> On the other hand, there’s no way to enumerate what variants we’ve
>   already created, but maybe that’s not really something people
>   generally need.

Surprisingly enough there doesn't seem to be any inbuilt method to easily return all variants